# Two Locations VPN and Printing Sluggish

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, printing, rras

I'm going to do my best to outline our current setup and our plan and hopefully you guy can assist in the best possible setup.

We have two offices (A and B).  Each office has about 10-15 systems.  3 systems in each office are attached directly (usb) to a printer.

Each office has a decent line with more than capable bandwidth.  Maybe I should be using VPN routers?

We have a powerful server (2012 r2) in a seperate NYC data-center with a full gigabit connection.  Due to having multiple locations needing to access the same software, we have setup a remote desktop services / domain controller on that system.  It also serves as a VPN server.

The office systems are all connected individually to the VPN server and assigned a static IP address (192.168.50.2-254).  The systems with printers attached in each office have the printer shared over the VPN.  The printers are then deployed using gpedit to all the users.

The printing however is extremely slow.  Test pages tend to freeze for a good 30 seconds before spooling.  Then it takes another 30-40 seconds to finish spooling and send it off to the printer.  We have another similar setup where we used server 2008 and it does not have this same problem.

Does anyone have any idea what could be getting in it's way?  Is there an alternate setup I should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time. However, I would like to encourage anyone who is having such an issue to ensure their VPN is a site-to-site setup. After switching to UBNT EdgeRouter with Site-to-Site OpenVPN, printing time is practically instantaneous.